# How to highlight cell conditionally in aura component datatable?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, aura-framework

I am building a lightning datatable with Aura component and I am showing data in this table from external system and I want to select one or more record so that I can import selected data in salesforce and after importing I want to to highlight that rows which had selected and imported in salesforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enter image description hereWhen you import data from external source than add an extra key  value in json or js-object.,let's say isExternal which has value =''slds-theme_success" and use it is cellAttributes in lightningdatable, you can use cellAttributes in each column to highlight whole row.
Ex:-

`Columns=[{ label: 'test', fieldName:'test' , cellAttributes:{class: { fieldName: 'isExternal' }} } ];`
[image]

Comment: Hi Umesh thank you for your help here, I am trying your above solution and I am getting error while saving controller.js file


 var tableData = caseRecords.map(data=>{
                let isExternal = SavedRecordSet.has(data.CaseNumber)?"slds-theme_success":"";
               return {...data,"isExternal":isExternal}

Comment: consider this example for inserting isExternal to object...in this example i check id similarly you can check CaseNumber
let a = [{"id" : 1 , "name" : "frontdesk"}, {"name" : "umesh"}];
let b = a.map((e)=>{
    e.isExternal = e.id ? 'slds-theme_success' : '';
    return e;
});

Comment: Hi Umesh, is it possible to disable checkbox which I have selected for importing from datatable so next time user unable to selected which already have imported?

Comment: Nope, you have to use custom solution for this.